# PHP Server Variable in Included Files

Tags: php, variables

I have a pages on my site which use other PHP files for the content.

Here is an example:

file1.php:

```
<!-- header and other stuff goes here -->

<?php include 'file2.php; ?>

<!-- footer and other stuff goes here -->
```

file2.php:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']; ?>
<p>Content goes here.</p>
```

My problem is that the SCRIPT_FILENAME variable is echoing out as file1.php because it is included in File 1. How do I stop that from happening and get the SCRIPT_FILENAME of the included file (file2.php).

Comment: Because it isn't in the server environment. But you can use the `__FILE__` & `__DIR__` constants as you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, I think you want this in your file2:

```
echo __FILE__;
```

Comment: Perfect, I'll tick it when it will let me :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo __FILE__;` to echo the full path of the included file.

check the manual here http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php